# How should I deal with unwanted attention when I start wearing clothes according to Islamic principles?

Tags: sunni, conversion

I am about to convert to Islam, and in my heart I am already a Muslim, but there is a big issue regarding my conversion and my question is:

As a woman in a non-Muslim culture, and non-Muslim family, and as a woman, what are my rights as a woman, and how can I protect myself in regard to physical safety/protection.

I will underline this, by a warning I was given some days ago.

A Muslim man said to me that I should expect a lot of unwanted attention the day I wear cloths according to Islamic principles, and I should prepare myself to basically become a hunted pray. Sorry for my words.

And since I am unmarried, with no Muslim family, I am unsure how to handle this.

Comment: I am unclear about the laws for an umarried woman in Islam, when she has no family to support her. In my case, my family is not Islamic. The country I am from is not Islamic, and we have state laws and regulations, but when it comed to marriage in Islam, and the laws and rules I am a lot in doubt how to proceed. As an example: I understand in an Islamic marriage, you make a contract. And hopefully if Allah allows it, peace be upon him, I will marry in the future. I hope it made it a bit more clear.

Comment: Please add this to your Question. Note we put Peace be upon him only after quoting Prophets (peace be upon them) for Allah we may use many expressions like (Glorified and Sublime be He) or (Exalted is HE) ...

Comment: I think scholars and most Muslims would say get married first, because a (good) Muslim Husband could teach you and help you through and clear some of your doubts. But you can have a job and work and everything but you should just consider some rulings like a halal job and not being alone in a closed room with only male colleagues ...

Comment: I apologize for my mistake, it was not in disrespect to Allah, Glorified and Sublime be he. My convertion is new. Its a process that have happen over the last months. So if I make an error, it is not out of disrespect, but lag of knowledge.

Comment: I understand i just wanted to correct you. In Islam the Intention is very important and I was quite sure you never intended to do that http://sunnah.com/bukhari/1/1.

Comment: Please what do you exactly mean by "Protecting yourself"? At first sight this would underline the option of marriage, this would give you  a kind of physical safety/protection. But if you mean protecting yourself from committing a sin or doing a mistake because you misunderstood some shari'a rules that could be a totally different. Therefore i still strongly suggest you to re-edit your Question to clearly point out what you want to know or understand, and if necessary split it!

Comment: I think the statement of that Muslim man could be wrong. But it totally depends on your personality whether *"you'll basically become hunted pray"*. But you should be aware of the fact that people will ask, wonder about your hijab and some will give tell you that you should turn back and maybe "attack" you with words and bad/Stupid remarks on your clothing.

Comment: Yes, a reason I will for now, when I convert, not wear the hijab. I will follow the rules of being covered correctly, but it can be done in many ways. Without drawing to much attention my way. My faith in Allah, the gracious, and the most merciful, is with him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Praise be to Allah.

If you think that wearing a head-cover in your culture is considered unacceptable and people around you may harm you for that, then it is not obligatory for you to wear the head-cover. There is no sin on you if you don't wear the head-cover in such a situation.

Comment: What constitutes a sufficient level of danger of harm, and which references do you have for this opinion?